# Comparing multiple columns to equality

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse, equality, startswith

This may be a very elementary question using [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) and [tidyverse tools](https://www.tidyverse.org), but I couldn't
find a good way to do it.

Let's suppose I have a data frame in a wide format, and I want to select rows so that a subset of columns has all the same value. Naively, I can do the following:

```
> df <- tribble(
    ~name, ~id,  ~cost, ~value1 , ~value2, ~value3,
    "a",     1,     10,       1,        1,       1,
    "a",     2,     20,       1,        2,       1,
    "b",     3,     50,       1,        1,       3,
    "b",     4,     45,       1,        1,       1,
    "b",     5,     70,       2,        2,       2
)


> df %>% select(
    value1 == value2 &
    value1 == value3 &
    value2 == value
)

# A tibble: 3 × 6
  name     id  cost value1 value2 value3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a         1    10      1      1      1
2 b         4    45      1      1      1
3 b         5    70      2      2      2
```

Now, let's suppose the number of the columns to be compared is very large (> 10). All columns start with `value`, so that we may have `value_something, value_otherthing, value_morething`, i.e., not necessarily numeric as in this example. However, if the number of columns is `n`, naively I have to create `n * (n - 1) / 2` comparisons, which is clearly unmanageable.

Is there something like

```
df %>% filter(all_same(starts_with("value")))
```

where `all_same()`compares all selected columns by [`starts_with()`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html) (or any other selector)?

[`rowwise()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rowwise.html) and
[`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)
didn't help me too much either.

Answer (score 5):

We may use `if_all` to loop over the columns from 'value2' to 'value3', check if the column values are equal with `value1`, `if_all` returns TRUE only for a row where all the column comparisons are TRUE

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(if_all(value2:value3, ~ value1 == .x))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  name     id  cost value1 value2 value3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a         1    10      1      1      1
2 b         4    45      1      1      1
3 b         5    70      2      2      2
```

---

Or if we want to use `starts_with`

```
df %>%
    filter(if_all(starts_with('value'), ~ value1 == .x))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! This is a nice and clear solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible base R option, where we can count the number of unique values to see if there is only 1 for each row (and just for the "value" columns).

```
df[apply(df[, -c(1:3)], 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1), ]
```

Or another option is to use `startsWith` to select the columns that start with "value" (instead of indices).

```
df[apply(df[, startsWith(names(df), "value")], 1, function(x)
  length(unique(x)) == 1),]
```

**Output**

```
  name     id  cost value1 value2 value3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a         1    10      1      1      1
2 b         4    45      1      1      1
3 b         5    70      2      2      2
```

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGB. This is a nice alternative if you know exactly where your columns are.

Comment: @an_drade No problem! However, we can also use `startsWith` from base R to select the columns instead of using the indices. I've added that option to my answer too.